# Insert data into server

Tags: php, android

I have problem inserting data into my database. The data can't be inserted and it does not show any errors in my Logcat. I have working on it but still can't solve the problems. This is my PHP code:

```
    <?php

    require ("config1.php");

    if(!empty($_POST)){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM announcement WHERE announceID = :announcementID";
        $query_params=array(':announcementID'=> $_POST['announcementID']);

        try{
            $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($query_params);


        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            $response["success"]=0;
            $response["message"]="Database Error1. Please try again";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }


        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if($row){

            $query = "INSERT INTO announcement (title,description,start_date,end_date,time)
                                     VALUES (:title,:description,:starDate,:endDate,:time) ";

                    $query_params= array(
                        ':title'=>$_POST['title'];
                        ':description'=>$_POST['description'];
                        ':startDate' => $_POST['start_date'];
                        ':endDate' => $_POST['end_date'];
                        ':time' => $_POST['time'];

                    );


                  try {
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                }

                catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
                    die(json_encode($response));
                }

                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "Update successful!";
                echo json_encode($response)

          }
      }
    ?>
```

Below is my java code:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh=new RequestHandler();
                HashMap<String,String> param= new HashMap<String, String>();
                param.put(KEY_TITLE,announcement_title);
                param.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION,announcement_desc);
                param.put(KEY_START_DATE,start_date);
                param.put(KEY_END_DATE,end_date);
                param.put(KEY_TIME,time);
                param.put(KEY_IMAGE,announcement_image);
                String result= rh.sendPostRequest(ANNOUNCEMENT_URL,param);
                return result;
            }
```

Appreciate is someone can point out the problems.

Comment: I cant find where you would send the `announcementID` - so I bet for an undefined Index error, that might be surpressed. -> make sure error_reporting() is on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You PHP Code Has Syntax error and Mysql preparement Placeholder error.**

**I Have Rewritten the Code kindly replace with your Old Code.**

```
    <?php

    require ("config1.php");

    if(!empty($_POST)){
//kindly filter the POST value
        $query = "SELECT * FROM announcement WHERE announcementID = :announcementID";
        $query_params=array(':announcementID'=> $_POST['announcementID']);
            $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($query_params);

/*
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $response["success"]=0;
            $response["message"]="Database Error1. Please try again";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }
*/

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if($row){

            $query = "INSERT INTO announcement (title,description,start_date,end_date,time)
                                     VALUES (:title,:description,:starDate,:endDate,:time)";
//re written by Ajmal PraveeN
                    $query_params= array(
                        ':title'=>$_POST['title'],
                        ':description'=>$_POST['description'],
                        ':startDate' => $_POST['start_date'],
                        ':endDate' => $_POST['end_date'],
                        ':time' => $_POST['time']
                        );

/*
                  try {
*/
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
/*
                }

                catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
                    die(json_encode($response));
                }
*/
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "Update successful!";
                echo json_encode($response);

          }
      }
?>
```

If your `$_POST['announcementID']` is a numeric number i can re edit the post with a Sanitize and Title post too.

Comment: Hi thanks, could I know what you have rewritten? I can't see the different.

Comment: Changes in ':announcementID' and $query_params= array() and echo json_encode($response); those are common mistakes :) Just corrected.. So the code is started working? So VOTE UP.. :) do you wanna filter or sanitize?

Comment: Now it shows "Database Error1. Please try again". could I know why?

Comment: Still not able to insert the data, could u please help :(

Comment: I have made the DB error 1 as commented to test. can you try now. in Web i dont use the error catch due to some times the error can visible to attackers So i dont use it.. So if the error is not fixed need to remove the catch so do you Need the error Catch ? because you are doing this for android app!!

Comment: Hi sir, now it do not show any message at the Toast in my apps. Still data cant be inserted. :(

Comment: Now i have removed all the Exception, and Do you really need Exception? and Toast needed? give a try now. If it not works i need to Work some more on that and Add me on FB : Ajmal Praveen so i can help you further.

Comment: Thanks, I have personal message you. Kindly check your messanger.